# How can I find and replace all references to a library in C++?

Tags: c++

I have programming experience, but not in C++. That said, I'm trying to remove a library from a project because it has restrictive limitations on its usage and I want to replace it with another similar library.

How would I go about finding every instance in which the library is called? I can see the file is included via the

```
#include "nameoflibrary\src.c";
```

But then how do I track down the unique variables and function calls that are actually being referenced in the code?

Comment: you should **never** include a "*.cpp" in the first place. Typo?

Comment: Remove the included headers for this library, you'll get compilation errors. Fix those.

Comment: Also, you probably don't do that too easily. How equivalent are the two libraries (calling format, enum declarations, if any, struct definitions, etc...)

Comment: @davemackey Including a .c file is just as odd as include a .cpp (which is what you had before). Typically .h files are what you include.

Comment: Did you mean `.h` instead?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using Visual Studio - right click at the nameoffile - Find All References.
2. You can also search for the "#include "nameoffile.cpp"" string at your solution

I think that the best soultion might be to remove the library and then compile and fix the error

Comment: I meant `#include "nameoflibrary\src.c";`